# how to access properties of promise that resolves two types

Tags: promise, aws-sdk-js

In my typescript/node code, I am following an example at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html, where I have a line as follows:

```
const { VersionId } = await parallelUploads3.done();
```

However, I am getting an error that says `Property 'VersionId' does not exist on type 'CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput | AbortMultipartUploadCommandOutput'.`. `VersionId` is a property of `CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/completemultipartuploadcommandoutput.html) but not `AbortMultipartUploadCommandOutput`.

To do different things depending on the returned type/class, I have tried:

```
import { CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
...
const obj = await parallelUploads3.done();
if (obj instanceof CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput)

}
```

but this leads to an error saying `'CompleteMultipartUploadCommandOutput' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` Would anyone know the proper way of properly handling the different classes/types that are returned by `await parallelUploads3.done()`? I want to use the `VersionId` value later, but if the returned value is of class `AbortMultipartUploadCommandOutput` I can do something like throw an error.